# QWebView shows blank page on Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: qt, qtwebkit, qwebview, raspberry-pi2

I am developing a Qt Web Kit application to run on Raspberry Pi 2. When I run the application on Ubuntu 14.04 on desktop it runs as expected. However when I run it on my Raspberry only blank page is shown. I also tried setting other HTML pages in QWebView, but that also ended in blank pages. I tried local HTML files, the ones from the internet and I even tried setting HTML text from code myself with setHtml(const QString &html) function. Sometimes, and I don't know why, depending on QString I set as HTML i get "**$66**" written in top left corner of the screen. It just doesn't make sens to me. At the end of the question are functions which I use to set web kit and web view. Is the problem maybe that I need to enable something or set some other parameters of MainWindow, which is inherited from QWebView? In my HTML I have a lot of images, actually that is all there is. I thought that was the problem, but simple HTMLs and some sites like google don't work too, so I ruled that problem out. Here is the code. It is compiled and there are no exceptions while running it, but it doesn't work as expected.

```
void MainWindow::initializeWebKit()
{
    _network = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    _cache = new QNetworkDiskCache(this);
    _cache->setCacheDirectory(CACHE_DIRECTORY);
    _cache->setMaximumCacheSize(CACHE_SIZE);
    _network->setCache(_cache);
    page()->setNetworkAccessManager(_network);
}

void MainWindow::initializeFrontend()
{
    QUrl startURL = QUrl("qrc:/Web/index.html");
    setUrl(startURL);
}
```